# How can I position an image in a UIViewController above a specified tab bar icon

Tags: ios, xcode

Many of my test users are not looking at the tab bar and so do not find some of my provided content. They then ask why it is not provided. As part of a 10 second intro sequence in a UIViewController I want to have a pointing finger image point to one of the tab bar icons and have a line of text indicate its use. How can I position the image so it always points at a particular tab bar icon?

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass UITabBarController. If you do that you can then access the tabBar property and add as many subviews as you want.

You can also try to access directly the current Tabbar of your app by calling from the viewController :

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar addSubview: myView];
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me a place to start. I am now working on it.